# Using Google Play Search via API or PHP?? Solutions

Tags: php, api, google-play

I'm trying to make a php based app stats system, that would run a search query on the google play store and for each keyword it would return with the ranking.

For example:

> keyword : Notes Lock
>
> appid : net.newsoftwares.noteslock
>
> Rank : #1

returned via simple search query on google play's search function.

SensorTower.com provides the same function for keyword rankings and im not sure how they accomplish it.

I've tried the following

1. Apptweak api :  provides only 20 results from the search query, i need 250
2. 42matters api : the results are from their own database and NOT the google play search function
3. `file_get_contents()` : to fetch the query url from play store

I tried with PHP:

```
$result = file_get_content( "https://play.google.com/store/search?q=football" );
// its only returns 20 app results, I want to get 250 results,..
```

The playstore shows only 20 apps on the query result, more apps are shown ONLY on scrolling.

Anyone got any ideas?

**Goal**: To retrieve 250 results from this query with php:
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=football

Comment: Have you tried something already? Maybe you should take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html

Comment: That is only for app developers to better manage their play dev accounts, uploading new versions etc.

Comment: What i need is access to the google play SEARCH function